# Expand the range of the xAxis to show a specific number of points for live data

Tags: highcharts

I want to modify the highcharts example for showing live data. It currently shows ~20 points and then pushes/drops off the oldest point out of the view when a new one is added.

What controls the number of points displayed? Or, how do I expand the axis to show a minimum number of points before the oldest one drops off?

http://jsfiddle.net/wjnoeo69/2/

(also posting the code, but only because stack requires us to....)

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }],

        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I have attempted updating the max property of the xAxis, but it only seems to set the range to 1. minRange seems to have no impact.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is adding and removing points:

```
series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
```

As you can see in [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint), third param stands for `shift`, to remove last point when new one is added. You can control removing points  by setting there false:

```
series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
```

So, there's no magic with 20points in the demo - just initial number of points is 20.